# In a Banach algebra, do ab and ba have almost the same exponential spectrum?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, open-problems, sp.spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a complex Banach algebra with identity 1. Define the exponential spectrum $e(x)$ of an element $x\in A$ by $$e(x)= \{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}: x-\lambda1 \notin G_1(A)\},$$ where $G_1(A)$ is the connected component of the group of invertibles $G(A)$ that contains the identity.

> Is it true that $e(ab)\cup\{0\} = e(ba)\cup\{0\}$ for all $a,b \in A$?

Equivalently, is it true that 
$1-ab$ is in $G_1(A)$ if and only if $1-ba$ is in $G_1(A)$, for all $a,b \in A$?

Note: The usual spectrum has this property.

Just an additional note:

We have $e(ab)\cup\{0\} = e(ba)\cup\{0\}$ for all $a,b \in A$ if

1) The group of invertibles of $A$ is connected, because then the exponential spectrum of any element is just the usual spectrum of that element.

2) The set $Z(A)G(A) = \{ab: a \in Z(A), b\in G(A)\}$ is dense in $A$, where $Z(A)$ is the center of $A$. (One can prove this). In particular, we have $e(ab)\cup\{0\} = e(ba)\cup\{0\}$ for all $a,b \in A$ if the invertibles are dense in $A$.

3) $A$ is commutative, clearly.

But what about other Banach algebras? Can someone provide a counterexample?

Comment: question poseé par TJR, n'est ce pas? It certainly seems to be quite subtle, but perhaps my intuition is faulty.

If I recall correctly, one can prove that this works when A is the Calkin algebra, by using properties of the Fredholm index. I'll have to check this though.

Comment: This sounds like a very interesting question. For an arbitrary Banach algebra, I would have thought that the answer is no. Have to think of a counterexample...

Comment: This probably ought to have a "functional-analysis" tag on it, if anyone with the power & inclination to bestow such is reading

Comment: So, anyone has comments / reading suggestions / ideas?

Comment: I edited to add LaTeX, to merge the additional note from the closed duplicate, and to make the title (an imprecise version of) the question. (I now realize that the additional note also appears in the answer below, but I think that it will be more useful in the question.)

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I didn't know mathoverflow supported LaTeX when I asked the question.



Comment: You're welcome.  Actually, I don't think there was LaTeX support back then.  Of course, feel free to revert or adjust any aspects of the edits I made that you don't like.

Comment: Grobler and Raubenheimer discuss this in a 2008 paper called "The index for Fredholm elements in a Banach algebra via a trace".  In section 4 on the exponential spectrum, they say about your problem: "Whether this is true in general for the exponential spectrum is still an open question."  Last revised edition: April 7, 2008.  Searching Google, MathSciNet, and the arXiv, I find no paper referencing this paper or more recently addressing the question.  Perhaps this is useless, as you have clearly already looked, but it seems likely that it is still an open question.  Maybe you could ask them?

Comment: Grobler and Raubenheimer do give some sufficient conditions.  Here's a link to their paper: http://journals.impan.gov.pl/sm/Inf/187-3-5.html

Comment: Can anyone say who is TJR ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to update this: a negative solution was recently given by Klaja and Ransford. See [arXiv 1510.08109.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.08109)

Answer (score 5):

Bonjour Yemon,
Oui, c'est un problème proposé par TJR dans le cadre d'un projet de recherche d'été CRSNG.

It is indeed a very subtle question, I thought it might interest some people here. This problem appears to be strongly related to the topology of the group of invertible elements, which is difficult to study.

And yes, one can show that the exponential spectrum of a*b is the same than the one of b*a in the Calkin algebra. It follows from the fact that 1-ab is of Fredholm index zero if and only if 1-ba is of Fredholm index zero.

Comment: Yes, it does. This was my first post, I was looking for "functional analysis" and "Banach algebras" tags, but for some reason couldn't find them, so I picked those two tags.

Comment: Do you remember how the proof goes for the Calkin algebra? I'm not sure if the proof I had previously found works, there seems to be a gap, or an error in my notes.

Comment: I'm sorry Yemon, I hadn't seen your comment before. 
hmm I forgot some key steps in the argument, but I have a pdf with the proof somewhere. I'll find it and then I'll send it to you via ulaval.

Comment: Did you receive the proof, Yemon?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Unfortunately the proof seems to rely on subtle properties of the densely-defined trace on B(H) - it's not clear how one might generalise to other Banach algebras. Even the C*-case could be difficult.